# How to use FETs to switch supplies in circuit

Tags: mosfet

I'm working on a project  that can be powered either by USB or an battery power supply. They can both be plugged in at the same time.I'd like the battery to provide 5V if its plugged in, but fall back to the USB if possible.
The one solution into my mind is using diodes.But i can't stand the voltage drop.As diodes will definately  drop some voltage.
other solution i have heard about is by using FETs.But i do not know very much about FETs use.
Will some body will guide me how to use FETs to switch between supplies in this scenario with explanation.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the battery even if the USB is connected? It would make more sense to me to primarily use USB and then fall back to battery.

Comment: What ever the sequence may be i just want to know how to use FETs in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of battery?  You can get power controllers for lithium cells that take care of all the problems, charging the cell and switching between USB and battery power.

eg http://www.sparkfun.com/products/726

If you wanted to do it yourself, you could use two MOSFETs (which can be thought of as a transistor with very low resistance when turned on), one controlling each power connection.   Pull the gate input up with a resistor on the battery, so that the power defaults to battery.

By connecting the mosfet gates to tri-state output ports on a microcontroller, it can it can choose which power supply to use once it has booted, overriding the pull-up/pull-down resistors.

This is likely to be very tricky.  The more usual approach is to have the external power charge the battery, possibly using a step-up converter.

Comment: So do i need an extra microcontroller to control the two MOSFETs And programme it to pull the gate inputs of desire MOSFETs (By connecting the mosfet gates to tri-state output ports on a microcontroller, it can it can choose which power supply to use once)

Comment: Watch the body diodes on the MOSFETs.  It's easy to accidentally make a battery charger that way.

Comment: When the microcontroller is in reset, the gates will be tristated and the pullups/pulldowns will control the behaviour (say, always use the battery during reset).   When the microcontroller has booted it can configure two pins as outputs and "override" the resistor biasing.

Comment: @unixbigot nice comment.But plese you will explain this line      When the microcontroller has booted it can configure two pins as outputs and "override" the resistor biasing.

Comment: @unixbigot, if you can sketch the schematic it will be helpful.  Make sure to show the body diodes on the MOSFET.

Comment: @zain when the micro is in reset its output pins will be tri-stated and the logic level will be 1 due to a pull up resistor.  When the micro enables output on the pin, if it outputs a 0 this will be a lower resistance connection to ground than the "weak 1" via the pullup, so will be an effective logic 0.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector).

Comment: @markrages I said it'd be tricky :)  I'm going to test this and see if I can make it work.

Comment: The charger from Sparkfun that you pointed to uses an MCP73831 charger IC. That's a very simple chip that specifically does not have any provisions for either power supply switching or dealing with powering the system load while the battery is charging.